# Python - matplotlib - how do I plot a plane from equation?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an equation z=0.12861723162963065X + 0.0014024845304814665Y + 1.0964608113924048

I need to plot a 3D plane for this equation in python using matplotlib. I have already tried following this post -- [Given general 3D plane equation, how can I plot this in python matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48335279/given-general-3d-plane-equation-how-can-i-plot-this-in-python-matplotlib)

However I am unable to set the x,y and z limits for this plane.

Can someone provide me the correct way of converting this equation into 3D plane. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have it easy since your equation gives the value of `z` for any values of `x` and `y`.

So choose any limits you like for `x` and `y`. You could even use the ones in the web page you linked to. Just calculate the `z` values according to your equation. Here is code modified slightly from the linked page:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

x = np.linspace(-1,1,10)
y = np.linspace(-1,1,10)

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z=0.12861723162963065*X + 0.0014024845304814665*Y + 1.0964608113924048

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

That is not the greatest graph, but now you can modify some of the parameters to get just what you want.